# Need to update Status in Task table of Salesforce Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

In my application, I used salesforce database. I need to update Status of Task field after click on a button. I used the code in html file for fetch the newStatus-

```
<a id="btnTaskUpdateStatus" href="#task_status_change_page" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">
    <img src="images/task_edit24.png" width="32" height="32" />
</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="task_status_change_page" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" style="width:280px !important">
    <script>$('select').selectmenu({ preventFocusZoom: true });</script>
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Update Status</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="select-task-status" class="select"><strong>Status:</strong></label>
            <select id="select-task-status" name="select-status" class="selectmenu">
                <option value="Not Started">Not Started</option>
                <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                <option value="Waiting On someone else">Waiting On someone else</option>
                <option value="Deffered">Deferred</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="center-wrapper">
            <a id="btnTaskUpdateSubmit" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" >Submit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in js file I used the code -

```
$j('#btnTaskUpdateStatus').click(function(e) {
    var recordId = $j('#TaskRecordId').val();
    if (recordId != null ) {
        var currStatus = $j('#TaskStatus').text();
        updateHTMLVal('#select-task-status', currStatus);
        $('#select-task-status').selectmenu('refresh');
    }
    $j('#btnTaskUpdateSubmit').click(function(e){
        var newStatus = $("#select-task-status").val();
        if (newStatus != currStatus) {
            changeTaskStatus(recordId, newStatus,creds);
            $('#select-task-status').selectmenu('refresh');
            $('#TaskStatus').html(newStatus);
         }
    });
});
function changeTaskStatus(Id, newStatus) {
    var fields = {};
    fields["Status"] = newStatus;
    forcetkClient.update('Task', Id, fields, function(response) {
             alert("Update");   
        }, onErrorSfdc);
}
```

Now my problem is that, When I update the Status, it will update properly, but next time I again change the status of another Task "`$j('#btnTaskUpdateSubmit').click(function(e){`" this function called two times, and the new Task's status overrite previous Task's Status.

If my qusetion is not clear then please guide me how I update the Task status in your way.
Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably stacking functions onto the $j('#btnTaskUpdateSubmit') element.  Try removing the current click event handler before adding a new one.  Like this:

```
$j('#btnTaskUpdateStatus').click(function(e) {
    var recordId = $j('#TaskRecordId').val();
    if (recordId != null ) {
        var currStatus = $j('#TaskStatus').text();
        updateHTMLVal('#select-task-status', currStatus);
        $('#select-task-status').selectmenu('refresh');
    }
    // Remove any existing click handlers
    $j('#btnTaskUpdateSubmit').unbind('click');

    $j('#btnTaskUpdateSubmit').click(function(e){
        var newStatus = $("#select-task-status").val();
        if (newStatus != currStatus) {
            changeTaskStatus(recordId, newStatus,creds);
            $('#select-task-status').selectmenu('refresh');
            $('#TaskStatus').html(newStatus);
         }
    });
});
```